# Login fetch data fast using linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have two table **UserTable** and **DeviceTable**, whenever user register devcieUUID store in DeviceTable. In UserTable **DeviceId** primary key of DeviceTable store in UserTable. I want to check deviceUUID is exsit in DeviceTable and bring particular UserId assign in **deviceId** using linq and in fastest way.

> UserTable

```
 userId userName deviceId
  1       xx1       2
  2       dd2       3
  3       cc3       4
```

> DeviceTable

```
 deviceId deviceUUID
  1       xx1                                  
  2       dd2       
  3       cc3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_context.DeviceTable.where(dt=>dt.deviceUUID == @deviceUUID).select(dt=>dt.deviceId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: Replace `@deviceUUID` by `UUID` with which you want to compare and if `exist in DeviceTable` then `deviceId` will be returned from `DB` else `default 0` will be returned.